# Grub-2 not booting Windows

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, grub

I have **openSuse 42** and **Windows 8**.

After a clean installation that worked very well (even dealing with UEFI), I just noticed that windows does not boot. I took a picture of the error I get

[image: 1].

This is the part of the **/boot/grub2/grub.cfg** that refers to Windows, where I assume there must be some error. This file was created automatically during the installation, and it is the same that **grub2-mkconfig** creates if I retry.

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menu
entry_id_option 'osprober-efi-969C-DCCA' {
    insmod part_gpt 
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-ef
i=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  969C-DCCA
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 969C-DCCA
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

I noted that the **/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi** path seems to be wrong, so I edited it to **/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi**. But then grub complains saying that it is not a valid image.

Any idea of how to proceed? Now the only way I have to load Windows is changing the boot order in the EFI settings, which is pretty annoying.

Comment: Well, apparently this is a known bug in openSuse. http://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=954126

Comment: Use firmware boot device selection key (F2 eventually, could be different key on your system) - you don't have to go to setup.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For the time being I have disabled Secure Boot, which is a workaround to avoid this until this bug gets fixed

Comment: The first path is correct, it goes relative to the EFI System Partition and not the linux mount point, which makes sense as within grub itself the linux context doesn't yet exist